# How to combine a bitcoin dataset and google into one dataframe as following?

Tags: python, z-index

Would you please tell me how to correct the following? When I run it, the error appears.

**ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
# set start and end dates
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 15)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14)
# extract the closing price data
combined_df = web.DataReader(["BTC-USD","ETH-USD","GOOG"],
"yahoo", start = start, end = end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
# pip install yfinance
# updated version of yahoo_datareader

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 15)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14)
symbols = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'GOOG']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in symbols:
    data = yf.download(i, start, end)
    df[i] = data['Adj Close']


df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

ind = list(df.index)

df.index = list(range(len(df.index)))
for i in df.index: 
    if df['GOOG'].iloc[i] == 0: 
        df['GOOG'].iloc[i] = df['GOOG'].iloc[i-1]

changes = []
for i in df.index:
    if i == 0:
        changes.append(0.)
    else:
        current = df['GOOG'].iloc[i]
        previous = df['GOOG'].iloc[i-1]
        perc_change = np.round(((current - previous) / previous)*100),2)
        changes.append(perc_change)

df['% Change'] = changes

df.index = ind
```

Comment: No problem, I often use this kind of data so have always tried to be up to date

Comment: However, I have just seen that a lot of data of google have been zero! I have lost them!

Comment: It is probably the last line (df.fillna). If you leave that out, you will just get NaNs on days where google was not active (i.e. weekends/bank holidays)

Comment: Is there any way to get ride of the zero? as I think these 0 could imply on statistics analyze.I am confused.

Comment: That is what the point of df.fillna(method='ffill') is. It replaces all NaN with the previous float. Howver you could do this:
for i in df.index:
    if df['GOOG'].iloc[i] == 0:
        df['GOOG'].iloc[i] = df['GOOG'].iloc[i-1]

Comment: Thanks. And my last question : How to make the last df to adj close pct change?

Comment: Do you mean add a column which shows the % change from the previous row? Or the % change from first value to last value?

Comment: I need both: add a column which shows the % change from the previous row? Or the % change from first value to last value?

Comment: This show nothing or is not a correct function: for i in df.index: 
    if df['GOOG'].iloc[i] == 0: 
        df['GOOG'].iloc[i] = df['GOOG'].iloc[i-1]

Comment: I imagine you are not using indentations and new rows and instead just copying the sentence I wrote, I will update the code above to show it clearly now

Comment: Thank you so much Sidney Driscoll.+1

Comment: Sorry ,another problem appears: I can not see Date index. As I would like to save it into excel.

Comment: I've just added a couple more lines to return the index to timestamps. I was originally dates but we had to turn the index into integers so we could read the dataframe easily. I've just added some code to save the original index in a list, and then later re-assign this list as the new index.

Comment: Thanks again.And would you please tell me how to name the index Date as Date? As, it has not any name such as Date

Comment: df.index.name = "Date"

Comment: Thanks  
Sidney Driscoll